# Placeholder text for registration form

Tags: user-registration

I am trying to add placeholder text to the native WordPress registration form. I am currently using the Register Plus Redux plugin. 
How to add this placeholder text into the text input fields on the form?

I need to tell people to use their first and last name as the username.
I'd be stoked if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 10):

Another simple way to do this without needing to add another script is using PHP's [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

```
$args = array(
    'echo' => false,
);

$form = wp_login_form( $args ); 

//add the placeholders
$form = str_replace('name="log"', 'name="log" placeholder="Username"', $form);
$form = str_replace('name="pwd"', 'name="pwd" placeholder="Password"', $form);

echo $form;
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this seems like the ideal solution as then you aren't relying on js, which could result in your placeholders not showing if user has js turned off or there is javascript error. And if you hid your labels then your form would be useless in that case.

Comment: This is DEFIENTLY the correct approach to this, NOT the JS option

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there are no hooks/filters to modify the input field in the login/registration form to add a placeholder to it.

But you can do this by simple jQuery. I am adding the steps below

I am not aware of how this plugin changes the form but you can follow the same for it too.
Below are the codes working for the default login/registration page

First you need to create a js file. I created it in my `active theme's js folder` and named it `custom.js`

then  added the below line in this file.

```
/**
 * Custom js file.
 */

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#user_login').attr('placeholder', 'User Name');
    jQuery('#user_email').attr('placeholder', 'User Email');
    jQuery('#user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'User Password');
});
```

The above adds place holder as `User Name`, `User Email` and  `User Password` to the `user_login`, `user_email`, and `user_pass` input field respectively. You can change those as per your requirement.

Now you need to add/enqueue this js file which you can do by adding the below code in your active theme's **`functions.php`** file

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_login_enqueue_scripts', 10 );
function wpse_login_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), 1.0 );
}
```

Comment: Maruti, YOU HAVE MADE MY DAY!. I can't thank you enough!!

Comment: Can't I give you, like, a gold badge or something? :)

Comment: Glad it helped, and about the badge, no you can't give a badge to me, atleast WPSE doesnt have that feature yet ;) but surely you can upvote my answer and accept it to give me the max 25 points from you :)

Comment: @mr_bythatmuch If this solution worked for you then accept it so that it helps other with same issue. [`how-does-accepting-an-answer-work`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Content to remunerate with gold but not marking as correct answer. SMH.

Comment: For future readers, placeholders [aren't supported on <IE10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder). Considering [2 of every 10](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) of your visitors use IE8/IE9, I recommend using a [polyfill plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/html5-placeholder-polyfill/).

Comment: What about localize support? I think you have to use `wp_localize_script`